# Inheritance of class attributes?

Tags: python, inheritance

Can someone provides a detail explanation why this is happening? How does Python compiler create class variables in this case?

```
class A(object):
    x = 1
    y = x + 1

class B(A):
    x = 10

>>> B.x
10
>>> B.y
2  # ---> I was expecting 11 here, why does this y still uses the A's value?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because class variables are evaluated at the same time the class itself is evaluated. Here the sequence of events is: `A` is defined and the values in it are set, so `x` is 1 and `y` is 2. Then `B` is defined, and the `x` entry in `B` is set to 10. Then you access `B.y`, and since there is no `y` entry in `B`, it checks its parent class. It does find a `y` entry in `A`, with a value of `2`. `y` is defined only once.

If you really want such a variable, you may want to define a class method.

```
class A:
    x = 1

    @classmethod
    def y(cls):
        return cls.x + 1

class B(A):
    x = 10

>>> B.y()
11
```

Comment: That was clearly what was meant though, it was tagged `inheritance`.

Comment: Both `A` and `B` inherit from `object`.

Comment: The OP's code has now been edited. I noticed that `B` did not inherit from `A`, but based on the context of the question it was clearly meant to.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `y` is a class attribute that belongs to A, so changing the value of x in a class instance of `B` does not change the value of `y`. You can read more about that in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Comment: Specifically, the value of `y` is fixed using the value of `x` at the time it is defined.

Answer (score -1):

It does not do that.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     x = 1
...     y = x + 1
...
>>> class B(object):
...     x = 10
...
>>> B.x
10
>>> B.y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'B' has no attribute 'y'
```

Comment: I suspect that OP meant to write `class B(A)`.

Comment: Why the downvote? This demonstrates that `A` and `B` do not share variables even though they both inherit from the same parent class.